# column of list values to one flat list in Python

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have pandas column with multiple string values in it, I want to convert them into one list so that I can take count of it

```
         df.columnX
Row 1    ['A','B','A','C']
Row 2    ['A','C']
Row 3    ['D','A']
```

I want output like

```
 Tag   Count 
    A 4
    B 1
    C 2
    D 1
```

I am trying to pull them to list but double quote is coming

```
df.columnX.values = ["'A','B',,,,,,,,,'A'"]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you actually have a list object in that column or is it actually a string? Eg,what does `df.columnX.map(len)` give you?

Comment: @JonClements Yes i tried, Its giving length of that row not count.

Comment: So you're probably after: `df.columnX.map(ast.literal_evel).map(len)`...

Comment: Not working, again it is giving length of that row.

Comment: Ahh... think I misunderstood what you were after... how about: `df.columnX.map(ast.literal_eval).explode().value_counts()` ?

Comment: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'
Explode means you want to say, split  ???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204053/discussion-between-ajay-jadhav-and-jon-clements).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it

```
flatList = [item for sublist in list(df.ColumnX.map(ast.literal_eval)) for item in sublist]


dict((x,flatList.count(x)) for x in set(flatList))
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this ?

```
df.explode('columnX').columnX.value_counts().to_frame()
```

Note that you need pandas > 0.25.0 for explode to work.

If your lists are in fact strings, you can first convert them to lists (as suggested by @Jon Clements) :

```
import ast
df.columnX = df.columnX.map(ast.literal_eval)
```